# creating simple cookies in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

My application needs to store cookies. When a user logs on I want to make sure that if the cookie does not exist create it and store value, but if it does modify it.

```
if(cookieExist)
 {
    cookiename = "value";
 }
else
 {
   create a new cookie 
   then store the value;
 }
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: It does not matter whether the cookie exists or not. If you issue a new cookie it will always overwrite the existing one. It means that you don't need `if`.

Comment: which part do you need help with,  it isn't really clear from the question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to use `Request.Cookies` to get cookie value and `Response.Cookies` to add cookies

```
 string cookievalue ;
 if ( Request.Cookies["cookie"] != null )
 {
    cookievalue = Request.Cookies["cookie"].ToString();
 }
 else
 {
    Response.Cookies["cookie"].Value = "cookie value";
     Response.Cookies["cookie"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1); // add expiry time
 }
```

Comment: you're adding a cookie that you haven't set to have any values

Comment: I also think you might encounter an exception by calling `ToString()` on a cookie that could be null.

Comment: @TrueDevelopment check added to avoid exception.