# How to create a cookie if it doesn't exist in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to create a website that says how many times you visited it. But i can't figure out why it doesn't work 
thank you in advance

```
        int intVisits;
        if (Request.Cookies["CkVisits"] != null)
        {
            intVisits = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Cookies["CkVisits"]);
            lblVisits.Text = Convert.ToString(intVisits);

            intVisits++; //to add a new visit
            CkNombreVisits["CkVisits"] = Convert.ToString(intVisits);
            //here its says that CkNombreVisits doesn't exist
        }
        else
        {

            HttpCookie CkNombreVisits = new HttpCookie("CkVisits");
            CkNombreVisits.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(20);
            CkNombreVisits["CkVisits"] = "0";
            lblVisits.Text = Convert.ToString(Request.Cookies["CkVisits"]);

            intVisits = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Cookies["CkVisits"]);
            intVisits++;
            CkNombreVisits["CkVisits"] = Convert.ToString(intVisits);

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating simple cookies in asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079332/creating-simple-cookies-in-asp-net-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You only need add `Response.Cookies.Add(CkNombreVisits);`

If you want to set expired `CkNombreVisits.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(6);`

```
 int intVisits;
  HttpCookie CkNombreVisits = null;
            if (Request.Cookies["CkVisits"] != null)
            {
                HttpCookie CkNombreVisits = Request.Cookies["CkVisits"];
                intVisits = Convert.ToInt16(CkNombreVisits );
                lblVisits.Text = Convert.ToString(intVisits);

                intVisits++; //to add a new visit
                CkNombreVisits["CkVisits"] = Convert.ToString(intVisits);
                //here its says that CkNombreVisits doesn't exist
            }
            else
            {

                CkNombreVisits = new HttpCookie("CkVisits");
                CkNombreVisits.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(20);
                CkNombreVisits["CkVisits"] = "0";
                lblVisits.Text = Convert.ToString(Request.Cookies["CkVisits"]);

                intVisits = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Cookies["CkVisits"]);
                intVisits++;
                CkNombreVisits["CkVisits"] = Convert.ToString(intVisits);

            }

Response.Cookies.Add(CkNombreVisits);
```

Answer (score 0):

> CkNombreVisits doesn't exist

Of course not, because you have it in the else branch only. In the if-branch, add

```
HttpCookie CkNombreVisits = Request.Cookies["CkVisits"];
```