# Saving random number value after site is refreshed

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, web

Hey I created a database with question. every question has a unique id (.ID) and a random generator randomly picks numbers and the the question with this number (id) is chosen and appears on the website.

So far so good but I want every question to appear a single time. Sadly every user request is unique so the values aren't remembered.

Is there an easy way to implement this to my code that my when form is transmitted my website still recognise the previous.

```
var questions = from m in _context.Question
                                select m;

var rowsTaken = new HashSet<int>();
Random r = new Random();

int rndRowIndex = r.Next(1, 10);


if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(QuestionLayer))
{
    do
    {
        questions = questions.Where(x => x.ID == rndRowIndex);
        //questions = questions.Where(x => x.Layer == QuestionLayer);
    } while (listids.Contains(rndRowIndex));
    listids.Add(rndRowIndex);
}
```

Comment: you can keep a list with the questionsId on the user side, and send it on each request, or you can keep some control of who is doing the request (mac address/ip/etc) and check that list before picking the question.

Comment: Okay can you give me an explanation or a link on how to do it im looking through the internet but cant really find something good

Comment: have a look at the cookies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079332/creating-simple-cookies-in-asp-net-c-sharp/12079406

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer about random number generator is no. However, you could keep track of questions answered or displayed by marking them in database. Then when random number is generated check the question associated with that number. If answered/displayed already either generate another number for the next question or using the first number generated look at the next question and the next until and so forth until you find the next unanswered question. When a question is chosen for display mark it in database as having been displayed.

Once all questions answered mark all questions as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Storage in the database is a good choice. If you don’t want to modify the database, you can use the `session` to store the randomly generated value each time.

More details, refer to the following code:

First, enable the session in your starup.cs :

- In `Configuration` method add `services.AddSession();`
- In `Configure` method add `app.UseSession();`

Then, in you controller:

```
            //retrieve the session 
            var str = HttpContext.Session.GetString("mykey");
            List<int> listids = str == null ? new List<int>() : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(str);


            var questions = from m in _context.Question
                            select m;
            //If all the questions have occurred, to prevent entering into an endless loop, we need to store the previously stored empty.
            if (listids.Count == questions.Count())
            {
                listids = new List<int>();
            } 
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(QuestionLayer)
            {
                var rowsTaken = new HashSet<int>();
                Random r = new Random();
                int rndRowIndex = r.Next(1, 10);
                while (listids.Contains(rndRowIndex))
                {
                    rndRowIndex = r.Next(1, 10);
                }
                questions = questions.Where(x => x.ID == rndRowIndex);
                listids.Add(rndRowIndex);
               //store new list to session
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("mykey", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listids));
            }
```